# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (@Arrays:checkOffsetAndCount:1719) {TubeSockReader-1}

Tags: android, arrays, firebase

I've gotten over 500 incidences of this error just for users with 'Samsung' branded devices, 'Operating System' 5.1, with 'screen resolution' 438x320 in the 'crashes and exceptions' section of my Google Analytics page. 'TubeSockReader' gives only 16 unrelated Google search hits, mostly 'page not found' results, but from the rare instances I've seen the term it appears to arise from Firebase database usage and the exception began about the same time I started using the Firebase database in my game.

The '@Arrays' points to java.util.Arrays use, which I don't import for my code, so I expect it's from hidden support code or related to Firebase database usage. Here is a 'checkOffsetAndCount' example I found:

```
public long read(ByteBuffer[] targets, int offset, int length) throws IOException {
    Arrays.checkOffsetAndCount(targets.length, offset, length);
```

Any ideas on where the source trigger would be for this odd error or what 'TubeSockReader' refers to?

[image]

[image]